# setting a limit/threshold for each value in a given row(s) of a matrix during a forloop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a for loop for projecting matrices in r and would like to set a "cap" or upper limit/threshold on the values of a given row(s) so they never exceed this values. Below is a sample code and I have commented out my attempt in the forloop. The goal being that any iterative results/results in the third row will not exceed 10000 at any point and if they do, they become 10000. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
set.seed(123)
A <- lapply(1:50, function(x)  # construct list of matrices
  matrix(c(0, 0, 10,
           rbeta(1,5,4), 0, 0,
           0, rbeta(1,10,2), 0), nrow = 3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE, ))

n <- c(1000,100,10)  # initial vector of abundances

nYears = 50  # define the number of years to project over

allYears <- matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=nYears+1)  # build a storage array for all abundances

allYears[,1] <- n  # set the year 0 abundance   

i1 <- 2:ncol(allYears)

for(t in seq_along(i1)) {
  #ifelse (allYears[3,i1[t]-1] > 10000,10000,allYears[3,i1[t]-1])
  allYears[,i1[t]] <-  A[[t]] %*% allYears[,i1[t]-1]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question clearly.
So you are trying to limit the values of the third row to a certain threshold.
I think your code is almost there.

After you decide whether to put the limit in one particular entry through `ifelse`,
you would like to save the (updated) value to your output matrix `allYears`.
Hence,
you can get the desired matrix you want.

```r
set.seed(123)
A <- lapply(1:50, function(x)  # construct list of matrices
  matrix(c(0, 0, 10,
           rbeta(1,5,4), 0, 0,
           0, rbeta(1,10,2), 0), nrow = 3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE, ))

n <- c(1000,100,10)  # initial vector of abundances

nYears = 50  # define the number of years to project over

allYears <- matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=nYears+1)  # build a storage array for all abundances

allYears[,1] <- n  # set the year 0 abundance   

i1 <- 2:ncol(allYears)

for(t in seq_along(i1)) {
  allYears[,i1[t]] <-  A[[t]] %*% allYears[,i1[t]-1]

  ### Check and update the entry for the output matrix ###
  allYears[3,i1[t]] <- ifelse (allYears[3,i1[t]] > 10000, 10000, allYears[3,i1[t]])
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: appreciate it. Funny, am almost certain I had this iteration of it at some point! nevertheless, this is it.